# How to dynamically adding and removing tabs in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs

I an trying to dynamically add and remove tabs in a TabBar, and it generally works, however when adding tabs Flutter throws an exception. I guess I am doing something wrongly, however it is not obvious what - if the tabs are defined statically everything is fine, when adding dynamically I do those 2 steps:

1. I update the model (TabsConfig class)
2. I trigger UI update via setState.

The tab is visualized, however in the console there is the exception below:

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building TabBar(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#f57c6], _TabControllerScope, _InheritedTheme, Directionality], state: _TabBarState#cf630):
Controller's length property (4) does not match the number of tabs (3) present in TabBar's tabs property.

The relevant error-causing widget was
TabBar
lib\main.dart:317
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _TabBarState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/material/tabs.dart:1159
#1      _TabBarState.build
package:flutter/…/material/tabs.dart:1165
#2      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4919
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4806
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4977
#5      Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4529
#6      BuildOwner.buildScope
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2659
#7      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:891
#8      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:370
#9      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1146
#10     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1083
#11     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:997
#15     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#16     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#17     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

And here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class TabsConfig {
  static List<String> tabs = [];
  static int selectedTabIndex = 0;
}

class MyApp extends MaterialApp {
  MyApp({Key? key})
      : super(
          key: key,
          home: const MainWidget(),
        );
}

class MainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainWidget> createState() => MainWidgetState();
}

class MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  void updateTabs() {
    try {
      setState(() {});
    } catch (on) {
      print(on); // TODO: rem
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: TabsConfig.tabs.length,
        initialIndex: TabsConfig.selectedTabIndex,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            getSliverTabBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          TabsConfig.tabs.add('New tab');
          updateTabs();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getSliverTabBar() {
    print('tabs: ${TabsConfig.tabs.length}'); //TODO: rem

    return SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      title: Align(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
        child: TabBar(
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          isScrollable: true,
          onTap: ((int selected) {
            TabsConfig.selectedTabIndex = selected;
          }),
          tabs: TabsConfig.tabs
              .map(
                (e) => Tab(text: e),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to make it work or what might be the cause?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate tabs dynamically you may have to use a Custom controller and use TickerProviderStateMixin instead of SingleTickerProver and update the controller when you update the screens. Made a demo for you to get started

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MainWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class TabsConfig {
  static List<String> tabs = [];
  static int selectedTabIndex = 0;
}

class MainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainWidget> createState() => MainWidgetState();
}

class MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    controller = TabController(
      length: TabsConfig.tabs.length,
      vsync: this,
      initialIndex: TabsConfig.selectedTabIndex,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  void updateTabs() {
    try {
      controller = TabController(
        length: TabsConfig.tabs.length,
        vsync: this,
        initialIndex: TabsConfig.selectedTabIndex,
      );
      setState(() {});
    } catch (on) {
      print(on); // TODO: rem
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              controller: controller,
              labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              tabs: List.generate(
                TabsConfig.tabs.length,
                (index) => Text("${TabsConfig.tabs[index]}"),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: controller,
                children: List.generate(
                  TabsConfig.tabs.length,
                  (index) => Center(
                    child: Text("${TabsConfig.tabs[index]}"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          TabsConfig.tabs.add('New tab ${TabsConfig.tabs.length}');
          // setState(() {});
          updateTabs();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```